# Text Field only gets visible after another action

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created a `UITextField` which contains `UIPickerView` and  `UIToolbar` to have a nice selection wheel with a "Save" and a "Cancel" button. pickerTextField is defined at the top of my class:

```
let pickerTextField = UITextField()
```

The rest is called when a user taps on a `SKSpriteNode` so I'm tracking the touch by overwriting the `touchesBegan` function

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
            if name == "overlay_player"
            {
                pickerTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view!.bounds.width, view!.bounds.height*0.5)

                let playerCountryPicker = UIPickerView()
                playerCountryPicker.delegate = self
                playerCountryPicker.dataSource = self
                playerCountryPicker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
                playerCountryPicker.layer.borderWidth = 1
                playerCountryPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                playerCountryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true

                var toolBar = UIToolbar()
                toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
                toolBar.translucent = true
                toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
                toolBar.sizeToFit()

                var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "savePickerPlayer:")
                var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
                var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPickerPlayer:")
                toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
                toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

                pickerTextField.inputView = playerCountryPicker
                pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

                self.view?.addSubview(pickerTextField)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

My issue is: When tapping on the `SKSpriteNode` the code is executed but the text field won't show. But if I tap on any other object (e.g. a second `SKSpriteNode`) the text field shows up, but without executing the code once more.

From my perspective it seems the view just isn't updated but trying it with

```
self.view?.setNeedsDisplay()
self.view?.setNeedsLayout()
self.view?.reloadInputViews()
```

has no effect whatsoever. I assume I'm missing a simple point here but I'm struggling to find it.
Any ideas?

/Edit: Found a work-around I can propose to persons with the same problem (not a solution thought):
Replace the `UITextField` with an `UILabel`. You need to set `yourLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true` and instead using `UITextField.inputView` and `UITextField.inputAccessoryView` you'll just add the `UIToolbar` and the `UIPickerView` as subviews.

You'll have to handle the animations yourself but a simple

```
class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval,
                    animations animations: () -> Void)
```

should do the trick. General question why two actions are needed to show the `UITextField` is still open.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `pickerTextField` subview is not at the front.

Try adding the following.

```
self.view?.addSubview(pickerTextField)
self.view?.bringSubviewToFront(pickerTextField)
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help - but was worth a try, thanks!